# Macbook pro (mid-2012) startup chime delayed (slow booting) after HDD to SSD conversion

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd

I recently upgraded HDD to SSD on my mid-2012 macbook pro.
After the SSD upgrade, the startup chime is delayed, causing slow booting of my mac.

Any potential pointers ?

Comment: Once booted, make sure the new drive is set as Boot in system prefs > startup disk. See if that speeds it up at all.

Comment: yes, I added new disk as boot disk, no change noticed though!

Comment: OK, it was just a thought. tbh, my old Mac Pro takes a lot longer to reach the chimes than it used to. idk whether it's since I swapped to SSD or whether it was after an OS upgrade.

Comment: You can also enable TRIM in that SSD https://www.howtogeek.com/222077/how-to-enable-trim-for-third-party-ssds-on-mac-os-x/ this may not speed things right now, but helps in the long run.

Comment: How did you do this "conversion?"  Did you clone the drives or did you do a clean install?

Comment: @Allan - I used SuperDuper (https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) to copy the existing HDD to SSD. I bought an extra SATA cable to connect SSD to the macbook, and copied HDD to SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid cloning a HDD to a SDD

The problem with cloning is that [you are making an exact copy of *all* the data on your drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310415/119271) at the block level - including the deleted data.

Spinning media acts and breathes differently than solid state media (i.e. [TRIM support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing))) and as such, you will be introducing problems for your SSD where none existed on the HDD.

**What do do instead?**

Do a clean install and utilize [Migration Assistant](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/195086/119271) to transfer your user data.

Comment: Disk cloning may have issues. However Samsung Data Migration/ Magician do similar work for data migration, or Apple utility is preferred for this task ?

Comment: I can't speak to Samsung Data Migration as I've never used it, but Apple's M.A is designed specifically to move macOS user data from one place to another *by* Apple.  I've used it countless times with no issues.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I will try using Apple's M.A. and see if that solves the problem.